# Does SSRS 2012 have significantly improved report writing features versus SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing serious problems with SSRS 2008 - the complex sophisticated reports are behaving odd and things are just not working as Microsoft documented - too complicated to describe them here. The development tool is VS 2008 BI Studio while the target server is 2012. Are there any significant improvements in VS 2012 BI Studio that would make it worthwhile to switch?

Edit:

As the volunteer censors pitched in, I think I can accommodate their concerns and limit the scope of this question.

I am having problems with tablix splitting just below the header row of an arbitrary section in the middle of the page and all its detail rows moving to the next page, if the total height of the rows happens to be an unknown unfortunate number. That can be avoided by microscopic changes to the header row height, which is annoying.

Another issue is that no matter what, the header rows refuse to repeat on each page. The tablix is set to repeat the rows, the statics in Advanced Mode are too set to repeat, but it's not repeating headers, but repeating a group which in turn is set to not repeat. I.e. it's doing the opposite of what the report is coded to.

Am I going to see any improvement in 2012 SSRS/2010 BI Studio compared to 2008 for the items above?

Comment: The phrasing of the question, especially the title, is going to put this in jeopardy of being closed.  Can you edit this to make it sound less opinionated?  Specifically "Better" is extremely subjective and impossible answer.  I'd suggest trying to reword this around the idea of evaluating specific features and not just an open discussion on whether switching is "worth it"

Comment: I am surprised I am reading this from an American. When did you guys stop valuing 1A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question arose due to uncertainty of what bug fixes exactly were included into 2012 SSRS according to [What's New (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx). None of the issues were addressed: report still arbitrarily splitting mid-page, there are still border alignment issues, headers are not repeating where required.